# How to use JSONArray variables in jsp

Tags: java, json, oracle, jsp

I use a node to open the server.
I can access the link to view the data in OracleDB as a json object.

JSONArray jsonrow = jsonObject.getJSONArray("rows");

There is a variable called JSONArray that is taken from JSONObject called jsonrow. I want to use the variable jsonrow in jsp.

for (int i = 0; i < jsonrow.length(); i++)

In Java, additional data could also be printed in the above sentence.

The second code is the jsp code that uses variables declared in java.
I can dynamically add data from getSleep, getSdate.

However, it only brings up the final data.

So i need the same way as jsonrow.length.

Please tell me how to do it. I need some advice.
Thank you.

```
package graph;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class getSleepData {

  String arraysdate, arraysleep, sleep, sdate;
  {
      try {
          String url = "http://220.81.195.81:4000/sleep";
          URL obj = new URL(url);
          HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
          int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
          System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
          System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
          BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
          String inputLine;
          StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
          while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
              response.append(inputLine);
          }
          in.close();
          // System.out.println(response.toString());
          JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());
          JSONArray jsonmetadata = jsonObject.getJSONArray("metaData");
          JSONArray jsonrow = jsonObject.getJSONArray("rows");
          arraysleep = (String) ((JSONObject) jsonmetadata.get(0)).get("name");
          arraysdate = (String) ((JSONObject) jsonmetadata.get(1)).get("name");

          System.out.println("col1  :" + arraysleep);
          System.out.println("col2  :" + arraysdate);

          for (int i = 0; i < jsonrow.length(); i++) {
              sleep = (String) ((JSONObject) jsonrow.get(i)).get("SLEEP");
              sdate = (String) ((JSONObject) jsonrow.get(i)).get("SDATE");
              System.out.println("sleep : " + sleep);
              System.out.println("sdate : " + sdate);
          }
}
```

```
    <body>
        <%
            getSleepData SData = new getSleepData();
        %>
        <%=SData.getArraysleep()%>
        <hr>
        <%=SData.getArraysdate()%>
        <hr>
        <%=SData.getSleep()%>
        <%=SData.getSdate()%>

    </body>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're actually asking. Is it about how to use arrays/collections on jsps in general? If that's the case did you have a look at [jstl](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/tld-summary.html) which has tags like `<c:forEach>`? Or did you try using Java loops in your scriptlets?

Comment: I'm sorry.
I wonder how JSONARray variables = ***; Jsp uses these declared variables.

Comment: Well, since you have an instance of that class you should be able to access its visible elements. However, the structure of your code (everything in the initializer block), the naming (have a look at the Java code conventions) etc. imply that you are very new to Java and probably programming in general. In that case messing with JSPs and JSON might be a little over the top for now. You need to get a firm grasp of the basics first - you can't even crawl correctly so don't try to run already.